# How to find keywords in arrays of scripts using Javascript hopefully client-side

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongodb-atlas, keyword-search

I'm facing this problem and I don't know the right approach to solve it. I have an array of keywords, for example:

```
keywordArray = ["Javascript", "Python", "R", "Data Science", "Front-end", "Amazon Web Services", "Amazon DynamoDB"]
```

Now I need to find just once occurrence in an array of string and return that occurrence. For example:

`stringArray = ["I love learning JavaScript but I would also like to learn Data Science using R", "I don't buy at Amazon", "RnB Music"`]

In this example I need to return an array containing `Javascript`, `Data Science` and `R`. If I remove the first string from stringArray, then it should not return `R` (I'm thinking it may be found in "RnB Music").

I would like to do this on the client side but I tried `indexOf()`, `contains()`, etc., but it isn't working properly.

So, can I do it on the client-side? if the answer is Yes, then how can I do this? If not, then is it possible to do it on NodeJS? Should I use a cloud service for this?

I'm currently using Angular, Express, NodeJS and MongoDB Atlas, which it has a Fulltext search service and works quite good. I may try to do it there but I don't know if its cost efficient.

Comment: so the ```keywordArray``` and ```stringArray``` are both present in your JavaScript code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so, you have the first array :

```
const keywordArray = ["JavaScript", "Python", " R", "Data Science", "Front-end", "Amazon Web Services", "Amazon DynamoDB"];
```

and the second one is the list of strings

```
const stringArray = ["I love learning JavaScript but I would also like to learn Data Science using R", "I don't buy at Amazon", "RnB Music"];
```

So you need to iterate over both arrays and check with `includes()` method.

Like this :

```
const keywordArray = ["JavaScript", "Python", " R", "Data Science", "Front-end", "Amazon Web Services", "Amazon DynamoDB"];
    
    const stringArray = ["I love learning JavaScript but I would also like to learn Data Science using R", "I don't buy at Amazon", "RnB Music"];
    
    const result_array = [];
    
    for (let i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++)
    {
      for (let d = 0; d < keywordArray.length; d++)
      {
          if (stringArray[i].includes(keywordArray[d]))
          {
            result_array.push(keywordArray[d]);
          }
              
      }
    }
    
    console.log(result_array);
```

Comment: Hey Aurelien_, thanks for your help. What about cases? That's why I wrote Javascript and JavaScript

Comment: If you want check in non sensitive case, you can take both strings and set both in uppercase before the comparaison